# Does "CPU" in the picture stands for the "core"?

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu

This picture which shows how Java programs use kernel threads. 
My confusion is whether the "CPU" in the picture stands for the "core", that is, if my cpu has 4 cores and supports for 4 threads, then the java threads I created in the program can be finnaly matched to these 4 cores, and every time in each core there is only 1 running thread. What's more, how about the cpu has 4 cores and supports for 8 threads, does it mean that each core will have 2 running threads each time? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular picture, "CPU" does indeed mean "core". However, this picture is simplified.

A regular CPU supports running 1 thread at a time per core.

All modern CPUs have [Hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which means every core "supports" 2 threads at a time. In this particular sense, 4 cores can support 8 threads. I put "supports" in quotes because the implementation is not really running 2 things at once - that would be just 2 cores. What it does instead is interleave the 2 threads, but have 2 sets of registers, so that it doesn't have to load the registers from memory when switching between the 2 threads.

The picture you have doesn't consider Hyperthreading at all, and for a good reason - it tries to teach you about threads, not CPU implementations.

Do note that if you have 1, 4, or 60,000 threads, that doesn't mean that they will divide evenly among the cores. A thread can run on different cores at different times, and the runtime (Java) can set [affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) for certain threads.

This means that it's possible that all your threads will run on 1 cores, or each thread on a different core, or any other combination.

Comment: Thanks so mush Sir! I have just one problem with your comment which is "I put "supports" in quotes because the implementation is not really running 2 things at once - that would be just 2 cores"  What does this mean? Can u help me to expain it more clearly. If the 4 cores can support 8 threads does it mean that it has the potential to run 8 threads concurrently?

Comment: The picture is not intended to depict the actual operation of a complex modern CPU. It's using an abstraction where a system has multiple CPUs and ignores complexities such as hyper-threading or multi-core CPUs. If it helps, by "CPU" it means whatever it is that the thread scheduler schedules a thread on.